# Send-Mailmessage timing out

Tags: powershell

I am looking to improve an old batch script and upgrade it to powershell, this is a robocopy batch script and i would like it to send a mail with the logfile attatched when it is finished. i managed to get the drive mappings and robocopy part sorted but im having some issues getting the send-mailmessage part to work

```
`$SourceFolder = "V:\"
$DestinationFolder = "Y:\"
$Dateandtime = Get-Date -format filedate
$password = XXXXXXXXX
$Subject = "Robocopy Results: Backup USA - NL"
$SMTPServer = "mailserver.domain.com"
$Sender = "backupusr@domain.com"
$Username = "backupusr"
$Recipients = "administrator@domain.com"
$Admin = "administrator@domain.com"
$SendEmail = $True
$IncludeAdmin = $True
$AsAttachment = $False
$Cred =  new-object Management.Automation.PSCredential $Username, ($password 
| ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)`
```

This is the line that causes the script to timeout

```
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -From $Sender -To $Recipients -Subject $Subject -Body "Robocopy results are attached." -DeliveryNotificationOption onFailure -UseSsl -Credential $Cred
```

this is the error i recieve

> Send-MailMessage : The operation has timed out.
>   At C:\Scripts\bpcti-robocopy.ps1:113 char:1
>   + Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -From $Sender -To $Recipient ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: quick edit: i managed to get the command to work without a password (i have to manualy enter it)


`Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer mailserver.domain.com -
    From backupusr@domain.com -To administrator@domain.com -
    Subject testing -Body "Robocopy results are attached." -
    DeliveryNotificationOption onFailure -Credential 
    "backupusr@domain.com"`


my question now is what syntax do i use for adding a password

Answer (score 1):

The `-Credential` parameter takes a `PSCredential` object. You can use `Get-Credential` to interactively create one using a username and password combination. More detail [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential?view=powershell-6).

Alternatively, as your password is already in plaintext in your script, you can use the process as described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/koteshb/2010/02/12/powershell-how-to-create-a-pscredential-object/) and construct a new `PSCredential`.

```
# Convert the plaintext password into a secure string.
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "XXXXXXXXX" -AsPlainText -Force
# Create a new PSCredential using the username and secure string password.
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("backupusr@domain.com", $SecurePassword)

Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer mailserver.domain.com -From backupusr@domain.com -To administrator@domain.com -Subject testing -Body "Robocopy results are attached." -DeliveryNotificationOption onFailure -Credential $Cred
```

Beware that the username should include the `@domain.com`.